# Access user's iCloud calendar without storing password

Tags: web-services, icloud, icloud-api

I would like to create a web application that would have access to the user's Apple Calendar for a personal project. But I really don't want to store the user's password.

With Google it was really easy using OpenAuth.

I know it is definitely possible as SunRise is doing it - http://techcrunch.com/2014/01/31/sunrise-calendar-stops-sending-icloud-credentials-to-their-servers/

I've searched Apple documentation and the closest thing i found was CloudKit. But it looks like it only provides a way to access your App's data across all the places. No mention of iCloud services.

Am i going in the right direction or is there a more direct way of doing this? Or is SunRise bluffing :)

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: oh boy. this was a while back and i havent really worked on it. I think iCloud has come up with 2 factor auth and One time app authentication. may be scenario has changed now.